# How does the linker know which archives to link together?

Tags: gcc, linker

Suppose that I'm compiling a simple *Hello World* program with `GCC`.

When run with `gcc -v hello-world.c`, we could get the last line from the output which generates the ELF binary:

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m
elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/crtbegin.o
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../.. /tmp/ccRykv97.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

From this output we could see that some objects like `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` are being linked together. But how does the linker know that these files should be linked togeter?

A separate but similar question is that, if I don't want to use the standard C library, when given a directory of object files that contain the definitions of these functions, how to know the files that are needed to pass to the linker, so that it won't complain about unknown symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we could get the last line from the output which generates the ELF binary

That *in fact* isn't the actual command that generates the ELF binary. `collect` in turn invokes `ld`, and *that* command generates the binary.

> how does the linker know that these files should be linked

It doesn't. GCC *told* it (by supplying them on command line).

GCC has a compiled-in `specs` file, which is a domain-specific language little program, that tells GCC what arguments it should supply to the linker.

You can examine the built-in `specs` with `gcc -dumpspecs`. You will see that the program is actually quite complicated, and that `crtbegin.o` is only used when `-static` and `-pie` or `-shared` are not. The `-shared` implies `crtbeginS.o`, and `-static` implies `crtbeginT.o`.

> if I don't want to use the standard C library

Use `-nostdlib` flag in that case.

> given a directory of object files that contain the definitions of these functions, how to know the files that are needed to pass to the linker

The ones that define functions that you use. [This](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) might help.